# Logstash with journald instead of rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog, logstash, journald

I'm used to sending my logs from a server to a remote Logstash using rsyslog, with a configuration file roughly as follows (usually more specific to prevent too many logs from being sent):

```
*.* @192.168.5.5:5000
```

I'm now starting work on a server that does not have syslog running but instead uses journald. Is there a similar way to send the logs to Logstash with journald as is done with Syslog, or does it require more work? I can't find much information online regarding the use of Logstash with journald.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official support, but [there is an open issue to get it added](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1729). It turns out there are a few plugins that shim in this support, notably [logstash-input-journald](https://github.com/vaijab/logstash-input-journald).

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably stick to using journald forwarding messages to rsyslog for now. This is probably still what most logstash user do to this date?

Answer (score 0):

There's journalbeat now to parse journald logs directly and send them to logstash

Answer (score 0):

You can tell journal to send messages to rsyslog by adding `ForwardToSyslog=yes` into `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`